# How do I set the value of a ContentPartRecord on a widget from the command line in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I have created a custom module in Orchard CMS. This module contains several widgets. One of these widgets (let's call it WinnersFeedWidget) contains a couple of custom Contant Part Records (let's call them NumberOfWinnersToShow and SkinName).

I can add the WinnersFeedWidget to a zone by using the command

```
widget create WinnersFeedWidget /Title:"Recent Winners" /Zone:"AsideSecond" /Position:"2" /Layer:"Default" /Identity:"WinnersContainerWidget" /RenderTitle:true
```

but I would like to be able to set the values of NumberOfWinnersToShow and SkinName from the command line as well.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You might have to write your own command.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. I did have a look at extending the Orchard command line tool for this purpose, but was wondering if there was an out of the box solution I had overlooked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone looking for an answer to this question-

Because I was creating a recipe, I was able to achieve the same effect by adding the following XML into the  element of the recipe:

```
<WinnersFeedWidget Id="/Identifier=WinnersFeed" Status="Published">
  <WinnersFeedPart NumberOfWinnersToShow="15" SkinName="Blue"/>
  <CommonPart Owner="/User.UserName=OrchardAdmin" Container="/Layer.LayerName=Default" CreatedUtc="2012-11-20T17:08:00Z" PublishedUtc="2012-11-20T17:08:00Z" ModifiedUtc="2012-11-20T17:08:00Z" />
  <WidgetPart Title="Recent Winners" Position="2" Zone="AsideSecond" RenderTitle="true" />
</WinnersFeedWidget>
```

In this instance, WinnersFeedPart is the name of the part on the widget.

I also had to update my driver class with overrides for Importing and Exporting (to allow the export feature to be able to correctly generate the required XML):

```
    protected override void Exporting(WinnersFeedPart part, ExportContentContext context)
    {
        context.Element(part.PartDefinition.Name).SetAttributeValue("NumberOfWinnersToShow", part.NumberOfWinnersToShow);
        context.Element(part.PartDefinition.Name).SetAttributeValue("SkinName", part.SkinName);
    }

    protected override void Importing(WinnersFeedPart part, ImportContentContext context)
    {
        part.NumberOfWinnersToShow= GetIntegerValue(part, context, "NumberOfWinnersToShow");
        part.SkinName= context.Attribute(part.PartDefinition.Name, "SkinName");
    }
```

(GetIntegerValue is a helper method that convert the value provided by the importer to an int)

For a good example of this working, I would recommend downloading the Featured Item Slider module from the Gallery, and looking at their Driver class.